# How can I create a workflow in Sharepoint 2010 that emails an assigned person ONLY when assignment changes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have created a Sharepoint Workflow in Sharepoint 2010 Designer that is currently set up as follows:

If Variable:prevAssignedTo not equals Current Item:Assigned To
  Email Current Item:Assigned To
  Then Set Variable:prevAssignedTo to Current Item:Assigned To

This workflow functions, but it sends the email any time the list item is updated, even if there is no change to the Assigned To.

I also tried using a boolean variable and helper columns as outlined on [another site](https://officepowerups.com/2013/07/09/send-email-when-specific-field-changes-in-sharepoint/) but it never triggered an email to send at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is only valid while the workflow runs. You need to create column '`prevAssignedTo`' in the list itself.

Then change your `Variable:prevAssignedTo` to `CurrentItem:prevAssignedTo`

Comment: Excuse my previous comment. I have set up 
     If CurrentItem:PrevCommentHistory not equals Current Item:Comment History 
Email Current Item: Created By
then set prevCommentHistory to Current Item:Comment History 

This does not generate the email either

Comment: I have set up another with the same process If CurrentItem:PrevCommentHistory not equals Current Item:Comment History Email Current Item: Created By then set prevCommentHistory to Current Item:Comment History This does not generate the email either. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure - if you follow the pattern it should work. Though I've always had problems testing multiline text fields in this manner, because they're always changing (all the hidden html). Make sure both fields are the same type of multiline - extended, rich, or plain. Usually I get too many emails instead of no emails :)  so I tell my users I can't test for changed comment fields.

Comment: This one was a user error. I forgot to set the workflow to automatically start when the item is changed.  It is working too. Thanks again for your insight.